# error in changing ** operator to power function using parsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have following pyparsing code for changing ** operator to power function using parsing. Paul McGuire helped me on this forum to write the following code

```
# define some basic operand expressions
number = Regex(r'\d+(\.\d*)?([Ee][+-]?\d+)?')
ident = Word(alphas+'_', alphanums+'_')
#fn_call = ident + '(' + Optional(delimited_list(expr)) + ')'

# forward declare our overall expression, since a slice could 
# contain an arithmetic expression
expr = Forward()
#slice_ref = '[' + expr + ']'

slice_ref = '[' + expr + ZeroOrMore("," + expr) + ']'

# define our arithmetic operand
operand = number | Combine(ident + Optional(slice_ref))
#operand = number | fn_call | Combine(ident + Optional(slice_ref))
inequalities = oneOf("< > >= <= = == !=")

# parse actions to convert parsed items
def convert_to_pow(tokens):
    tmp = tokens[0][:]
    ret = tmp.pop(-1)
    tmp.pop(-1)
    while tmp:
        base = tmp.pop(-1)
        # hack to handle '**' precedence ahead of '-'
        if base.startswith('-'):
            ret = '-power(%s,%s)' % (base[1:], ret)
        else:
            ret = 'power(%s,%s)' % (base, ret)
        if tmp:
            tmp.pop(-1)
    return ret

def unary_as_is(tokens):
    return '(%s)' % ''.join(tokens[0])

def as_is(tokens):
    return '%s' % ''.join(tokens[0])


# simplest infixNotation - may need to add a few more operators, but start with this for now
arith_expr = infixNotation( operand,
    [
    ('-', 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, as_is),
    ('**', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, convert_to_pow),
    ('-', 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, unary_as_is),
    ((inequalities,inequalities), 3, opAssoc.LEFT, as_is),
    (inequalities, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, as_is),
    (oneOf("* /"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT, as_is),
    (oneOf("+ -"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT, as_is),
    (oneOf('and or'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT, as_is),
    ])
#('-', 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, as_is),
# now assign into forward-declared expr
expr <<= arith_expr.setParseAction(lambda t: '(%s)' % ''.join(t))

#Changing function of the formate f(n) to f[n]. It assist the pasring 

def transferToFunctionSyntax(expression):
    if "(" in expression and ")" in expression:
        p = regex.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*\))')
        result=(p.sub(lambda m: m.group().replace("(", "[").replace(")", "]"), expression))
    else:
        result=expression
    return result

def translatepowerToFun(expression):
    expression=transferToFunctionSyntax(str(expression))
    xform = expr.transformString(expression)[1:-1]
    xform=xform.replace('[','(')
    expression=xform.replace(']',')')
```

when I call following, it return `"RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"`.

```
translatepowerToFun('(((2.00000000000000)*(((xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1))+((-__v2(_n1)*xn8(_n1, __VERIFIER_nondet_double2(_n1))**3 + xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1)))/(2.00000000000000)))-xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1)))))>((1.00000000000000e-6)*(((xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1))+((-__VERIFIER_nondet_double2(_n1)*xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1))**3 + xn8(_n1, __VERIFIER_nondet_double2(_n1)))/(2.00000000000000)))+(xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1))+((-__v2(_n1)*xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1))**3 + xn8(_n1, __v2(_n1)))/(2.00000000000000)))))))')
```

Can anyone suggest what can I do to avoid that?

Comment: Are you using packrat parsing mode? When you have a deep `infixNotation` expression, enabling packrat parsing can address performance *and* memory problems.

Comment: Also, what version of pyparsing are you using? Packrat parsing was completely rewritten around 2.0.4, with improvements in speed and memory.

Comment: I am using version 2.1.5, Yes I have enabled packrat parsing mode(ParserElement.enablePackrat())

Comment: Can you start with a simpler expression, then slowly add to it until you hit the recursion limit? It may be that sometimes you just need more recursion stack than the default of 1000. The limit is there to avoid runaway coding errors, but I'm pretty sure that this code *will* terminate.